# How to declare a Factory attribute that is an attribute of a RelatedFactory

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

```
class ValuationFactory(BEFactory):
   loan = factory.RelatedFactory(LoanApplicationFactory, 'valuation')
   security = factory.SelfAttribute('loan.security')
```

This raises `AttributeError: The parameter 'loan' is unknown.` It works when loan is a SubFactory but loan has a foreign key relation back to the Valuation so I end with with infinite recursion if I try that.

It seems like RelatedFactory is bound quite late and I can't even access it from `@factory.post_generation` methods safely because the factory tries to save to the database before the `create` phase and generates a database `IntegrityError` because `security_id` is null. I don't know if I can bind attributes in the build phase. Are there other techniques that would work?